# Making a boxed minipage environment

Tags: environments, framed, braces

I am writing up a document where I frequently want to put multiple paragraphs of text inside a box. I am doing this with

```
\framebox{\begin{minipage}{0.95 \textwidth}
Here is how you solve this problem.

Here is more of the solution.
\end{minipage}}
```

I wanted to make my work easier by defining an environment for this, so I tried:

```
\newenvironment{soln}
   {
     \framebox{\begin{minipage}{0.95 \textwidth}
   }
   {
     \end{minipage}}
   }
```

Not surprisingly, this gives the "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" error when I try to use this environment. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: something I made for my self in the answer below -- may appeal -- or not -- have alook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `framebox` and width box width equal to text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\solbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}%
{
\@parboxrestore%
\begin{lrbox}{\solbox}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
\framebox{\usebox\solbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{sol}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][4-6]
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have narrower `framebox` centered in text, than you can use the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\newsavebox\solbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}%
{
\@parboxrestore%
\begin{lrbox}{\solbox}%
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\begin{center}
\framebox{\usebox\solbox}
\end{center}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{sol}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][4-6]
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text boeders)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{pdfrender,xcolor}
\usepackage{palatino}
\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.2pt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{array, tabularx}
%\usepackage{booktabs}


\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{myBox}{Project}{separator sign={\ :}}{myBox}
            
            \newlength\mylength
                \settowidth\mylength{Contract Placing Authority}
                \setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\mylength+\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                
        
        \newlength\mylowerlength
        \settowidth\mylowerlength{77 SSS 2020}
        \setlength\mylowerlength{\dimexpr\mylowerlength+\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        
\begin{document}
    \begin{myBox}[grow to right by=3cm,grow to left by=3cm,]{K9}{}
        Assignment List -- Policy\\
        Assignemnt List noting sheet\\
        Cables from battery\\
        CES\\
        Assignment list -- forward for approval 
        \begin{myBox}{MAG 15}{}
21 items\\
        \end{myBox}
    \begin{myBox}{MAG 20}{}
Signature
    \end{myBox}
    \end{myBox}\newpage

\end{document}
```